# angularjs factories seem to be created lazily

Tags: angularjs

Today I am experiencing something really odd which I have never read about.

Just think the debugger is on the "var startDateOfWeek..." line.

With my mouse pointer I hover over the wizardDataFactory object. This object is not instantiated when there is not the line of code "var x = ..." which comes later...

WHY is that? I have never read something about factories are somehow lazily instantiated?

Well I do not want to complain because actually thats a good thing. Do not instantiate when the factory is unused in code.

Can someone please share a link where I can read about that?

```
   'use strict';
    angular.module('iplanmylessons').service('periodService', function ($q, $http, datetimeFactory, weeklyDataGridViewModelFactory, wizardDataFactory) {

        this.getWeeklyPeriods = function (schoolyearId, firstDayOfWeek) {

            var startDateOfWeek = datetimeFactory.getFirstDateOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
            var endDateOfWeek = datetimeFactory.getLastDateOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);

            var x = wizardDataFactory.transform();


            return [];
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct.

`wizardDataFactory` is initialized as soon as any other component requests it as a dependency.

The hovering undefined is probably due to a browser error.

Comment: there is no undefined error. I have not said that. I hover over the variable and nothing happens. When I hover to the next injected factory I get the object literal with its functions.

Comment: I said this:" Do not instantiate when the factory is unused in code." Why is my understanding not correct? And when there is no other component request because of unused code -what I said- what do we have then?

Comment: The factory is instantiated not when it's used but when it's **injected** for the first time. Injection occurs when you put the name of your Factory in the arguments of a Controller function